# Cardview not fitting in screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a CardView. In that I have a relative layout and inside that I have 4 text views.
In my activity I have a Linear Layout in that a Recycler View.
I have a GridlayoutManager set to the recycler view.It is horizontally scrollable.

[image]

[image]

The cards are getting created by the size of the text in the text view of the card.

My code:

Activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_page);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        data_list = new ArrayList<>();
        load_data();
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

AdapterClass:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<MyData> my_data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
        itemView.setMinimumWidth(parent.getMeasuredWidth());
        itemView.setMinimumHeight(parent.getMeasuredHeightAndState());
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.userstory.setText(my_data.get(position).getUserstory());
        holder.tasks.setText(my_data.get(position).getTask());
        holder.actual.setText(my_data.get(position).getActuals());
        holder.estimate.setText(my_data.get(position).getTodos());
        holder.seekBar.setMax(my_data.get(position).getEstimate());
        holder.seekBar.setProgress(my_data.get(position).getActual());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return my_data.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView userstory,tasks,actual,estimate;
        public SeekBar seekBar;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            userstory=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserStory);
            tasks=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTask);
            actual=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvActual);
            estimate=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEstimate);
            seekBar=(SeekBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        }
    }
}
```

Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/tvUserStory"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:text="@string/us" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/tvTask"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvUserStory"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:text="@string/task" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/tvActual"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvTask"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:text="@string/actual" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/tvEstimate"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvActual"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:text="@string/estimate" />



            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvEstimate"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:indeterminate="false"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I just want the card size to fit the screen.ie if the text does not fit in one line it should get to the next line and not expand horizontally.
[image]

Comment: if you span is 1 the use linear layout manager

Comment: Add left and right margins to textview as well.

Comment: yeah..my span is 1..I want one card at a time and same card sizes

Comment: @Akshay don't worry liniar layout manager also do the same... or can you provide the concept ui here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For single span count use `LinearLayoutManager`for adapter

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                 new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Change your cardview code like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tvUserStory"
            android:text="@string/us" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tvTask"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvUserStory"
            android:text="@string/task" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tvActual"
            android:text="@string/actual" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tvEstimate"
            android:text="@string/estimate" />

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
            android:indeterminate="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Is it a linear layout or relative layout?you have opened a linear layout and closed a relative layout..edit please

Comment: The textviews being displayed side by side..not one below the other

Comment: @Akshay Put `android:orientation="vertical"` on the `LinearLayout`. Default orientation of a linear layout is horizontal.

Comment: @Akshay i forgot to put `android:orientation="vertical"` in linear layout

Comment: I tried it..the card size is same but content is not getting fully displayed

Comment: See my edit..it is getting displayed like the image I have added

Comment: @Akshay set the linear layout to match_parent ... it will work

Comment: When I change textview to wrap content it displays entire thing and if match parent then it is showing as the above image

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines , in order to remove padding.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

Comment: @Akshay That's weird, because when there's no padding, content will draw on the whole screen. This fixes at least part of the problem and I don't get that vibe from `Nope..`. Always be specific when reacting.

Answer (score 0):

1. To make your cards fit the screen:
   Use `RelativeLayout` for the parent of your `RecyclerView` and `CardView`.
2. To make your text in `TextView` go to next line:
   Use `android:maxLines` attribute for your `TextView`

Comment: NEVER use `RelativeLayout` as *root element*! It has low performance (always measures children twice).

Comment: @EugenPechanec Then what's more performant as a root element?

Answer (score 0):

Move *horizontal padding* from the root layout to the `RecyclerView` and *disable clipping to padding*.

```
<RecyclerView
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Now contents of the `RecyclerView` will draw over the whole screen width. Content will still start at `16dp` when you open the window but will be visible while scrolling past padding.

Comment: I want the text which is going out of screen to be in the next line

Comment: Can you please guide me on this...When I change textview in the card(Linaear Layout) to wrap content it displays entire thing (card size extending the size of screen)and if match parent then it is showing as the above image

Comment: Everything in the card (including the card) should have width set to `match_parent`. Don't use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: In Linear layout inside the card when everything is set to match parent the first textview covers the entire screen and anything else is not shown

Comment: @Akshay Just width, not height of course. Height should be wrap_content.

Answer (score -2):

You can use padding in CardView.